# I am starting a project on Pyspark today and need help in defining cluster resources

Tags: pyspark

The data size s 25 gb and transformations are selcting required columns, creating other based on two and then aggregation. I need help in understand the starting point of assuming my cluster resources. I understand it is a hit and trial thing to optimize resources, but where should I start and what factors should I consider.

I have not started, but need to understand the number of executors, driver/executor memory I should provide initially to run the job without any OOM error.